# How to add column to represent the year variable, as the data is scraped?

Tags: r

How can I **scrape** the data and add and additional column to show the `year` that it is scraped?

```
nba_drafts <- function(year) {
    url <- glue("https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_{year}.html")
    
    tables<-read_html(url) %>% 
      html_nodes("#stats") %>% 
      html_table() %>%
      as.tibble() %>%
      add_column(year = year)
    
    write.csv(tables, year, file = "nba_draftsR.csv", na ="")
  }

2000:2017 %>%
  walk(function(year) {
    nba_drafts(year) 
  })
```

> Error: Column 1 must be named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked your code, the error is happening at the step highlighted in below code.

```
tables<-read_html(url) %>% 
      html_nodes("#stats") %>% 
      html_table() %>%
      as.tibble() %>% # error is happening at this step
```

`Debug Step:`
The reason for this error is the first three columns names are balnks`("")`, which you need to assign first, then only you can change to tibble or data frame.

```
tables<-read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes("#stats") %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    purrr::simplify() %>%
    first() 
names(tables)
 [1] ""         ""         ""         "Round 1"  "Round 1"  ""         "Totals"   "Totals"   "Totals"   "Totals"   "Totals"  
[12] "Shooting" "Shooting" "Shooting" "Per Game" "Per Game" "Per Game" "Per Game" "Advanced" "Advanced" "Advanced" "Advanced"
```

I have added a for loop to update the names

```
nba_drafts <- function(year) { 
  url <- glue("https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_{year}.html")
  tables<-read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes("#stats") %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    purrr::simplify() %>%
    first() 

  oldName<-names(tables)
  #updating names with col_
  for(i in 1:length(oldName)){

    oldName[i]<- paste0("col_",i,oldName[i])
  }

  names(tables)<-oldName
  tables<-tables %>% 
    as.tibble() %>%
    add_column(year = year)
  return(tables)
}
```

Output:

```
> nba_drafts("2019")
# A tibble: 63 x 23
   col_1 col_2 col_3 `col_4Round 1` `col_5Round 1` col_6 col_7Totals col_8Totals col_9Totals col_10Totals col_11Totals
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr>          <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       
 1 Rk    Pk    Tm    Player         College        Yrs   G           MP          PTS         TRB          AST         
 2 1     1     NOP   Zion Williams… Duke           1     19          565         448         129          41          
 3 2     2     MEM   Ja Morant      Murray State   1     59          1771        1041        208          409         
 4 3     3     NYK   RJ Barrett     Duke           1     56          1704        803         279          143         
 5 4     4     LAL   De'Andre Hunt… Virginia       1     63          2018        778         286          112         
 6 5     5     CLE   Darius Garland Vanderbilt     1     59          1824        728         111          229
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Nirbhay! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Glad to help. If my suggestion suitably answers your question, please upvote and click the tick mark to accept it as the chosen answer.